# Declaring a static member function const or virtual

Tags: c++

Why can't static member function be declared const?

I know a static function doesn't act on any particular instance of class. This means such function has no this pointer (passed implicitly as hidden argument) to any particular instance. But i don't understand why there is a compiler error when it is declared const, since it is not changing any particular instance.

Secondly, why can't static member function be declared virtual?

Need some clarification on this.

Comment: Why do you need "guidance"? Just don't add `const` to static member functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why there is a compiler error when it is declared const

`const` means "`this` is a pointer to a `const` object". Since there's no `this`, there's nothing for `const` to modify.

> why can't static member function be declared virtual

`virtual` means "select the right function based on the actual dynamic type of `this`". Since there's  no `this`, there's nothing to base the selection on.